# Using ctrl-h for backspace in kde apps

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I set up GTK Applications to interpret <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> as a backspace, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> to delete the part of the line before the cursor and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> to delete the previous word, by adding the following:

```
gtk-key-theme-name = "Emacs"
```

in the `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file.

Is there a way to do this for KDE Applications? (I am on KDE4, but an answer for KDE is welcome too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs does not adhere to the [Common User Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_User_Access) standard, but KDE does, you will not find these specific shortcuts. There are workarounds.

You may redefine or supplement these predefined shortcuts in the Control Centre or System Settings:

```
Ctrl+Backspace      delete word backward
Ctrl+Delete         delete word forward
Ctrl+K              delete line
```

Using the Control Centre, you may set up a keyboard macro that plays back the following sequences on for instance the trigger `Ctrl+u`.

```
Shift+Home, Delete      select from the cursor to the beginning of the line, delete selected text
Shift+End, Delete       select from the cursor to the end of the line, delete selected text
```

The `Backspace` key's functionality, namely deleting one character backward, seems to be hard-coded into Qt. Again, you can use a macro to play back Backspace on the trigger `Ctrl+h`.

Comment: Hey, that does work.  In kde4, i used the "input actions" module, in system settings. Thanks a lot!